# Cross-validation - how to estimate mean standard error

Tags: cross-validation

Reading the wikipedia article on Cross-validation there is an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Example:_linear_regression) given for linear regression which contains the statement

> If the model is correctly specified, it can be shown under mild assumptions that the expected value of the MSE for the training set is (n − p − 1)/(n + p + 1) < 1 times the expected value of the MSE for the validation set.

(in this case $n$ is the number of $\bf x$ vectors (covariates) which are of dimension $p$)

It is followed by a reference which appears to be irrelevant.

A commenter has observed that the statement seems empirically to be correct.

Can anyone suggest a derivation of the $(n-p-1)/(n+p+1)$ factor or point to a reference where it is derived?